# mailto attribute isn't working in all modern browsers

Tags: html

I wrote a simple code to test mailto attribute

```html
  <button style="background-color: #0288D1" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
                                <a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com?Subject=Getting%20source%20code" style="color: #ffffff;" target="_blank">    Contact us
                                </a>
                            </button>
```

This code works in `Chrome 62.0.3202.94`. But doesn't work in `Firefox 57 (Quantum)` and in `Microsoft Edge`. How can I make above code a cross browser solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons and anchors cannot be nested, they are both action elements that will try to capture the click event.

You can either make your outer `<button>` a `<span>` or put your styles and classes directly on the anchor.